# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 Suddenly appeared today without me changing any code

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, request

[image]Hey there,

I'm currently working on an airbnb clone and I wanted to start my local server through npm run dev and it gave me the following error. I'm sot sure why this morning everything was working perfectly but now it doesn't anymore even though I did not change or do anything. I searched online and people say the response might be html instead of json but how would that happen all of a sudden?? I also got a deployed version that you can access here https://airbnb-smoky-six.vercel.app
https://airbnb-smoky-six.vercel.app
It would be great if someone could guide me through fixing it.

The file refers to contains the following code:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Header from '../Components/Header.js'
import Banner from '../Components/Banner.js'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import SmallCard from '../Components/SmallCard.js'
import MediumCard from '../Components/MediumCard.js'
import LargeCard from '../Components/LargeCard.js'
import Footer from '../Components/Footer.js'

export default function Home({exploreData, cardsData}) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <Header />
      <Banner />
      <main className='max-w-6xl mx-auto px-12 sm:px-16'>
        <section className='pt-6'>
          <h2 className='text-4xl font-semibold pb-5'>Explore Nearby</h2>
          
          {/* Pull name from a server - API endpoints */}
          <div className='grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 '>
            {exploreData?.map(({img, distance, location}) => (
              <SmallCard
                key={img} 
                img={img} 
                distance={distance} 
                location={location}  
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </section>

        <section>
          <h2 className='text-4xl font-semibold py-8'>Live Anywhere</h2>
          {/* pull data from API endpoints */}
          <div className='flex space-x-3 overflow-scroll scrollbar-hide p-3 -ml-3'>
            {cardsData?.map(({ img, title }) => (
              <MediumCard
              key={img}
              img={img}
              title={title}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </section>

        <section>
          <LargeCard
            img="https://links.papareact.com/4cj"
            title="The Greatest Outdoors"
            description="Wishlist curated by Airbnb"
            buttonText="Get Inspired"
          />
        </section>
      </main>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const exploreData = await fetch('https://links.papareact.com/pyp')
  .then (
    (res) => res.json()
  );

  const cardsData = await fetch('https://links.papareact.com/zp1')
  .then (
    (res) => res.json()
  );
  
  return{
    props: {
      exploreData,
      cardsData,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: You backend service is already down. Access https://links.papareact.com/pyp return 502. You may log your response or set some breakpoint to debug.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `fetch()`, it returns a promise that resolves with a Response type. That response has a body that contains some text.

If you are sure the text is formatted in JSON, you can call the `res.json()` and it should return a promise resolved with the parsed value from the body.

However if the response text had some problem in the formatting of JSON (or didn't even include JSON at all), then you get the problem mentioned in your question.

Assuming the API you are trying to reach cannot guarantee you the response will always be a string formatted in JSON, you should handle the SyntaxError yourself:

```
const responseText = await res.text()
let responseValue
try {
  responseValue = JSON.parse(responseText)
}
catch (error) {
  // Failed to parse JSON from the response text
  // Need to handle it somehow. In this example,
  // I simply let it be the plain text string
  responseValue = responseText 
}
```

You should also think about this: making a request is not always going to be successful. Maybe you do not have an Internet connection. Maybe you do, but your server sends a response that is not successful. In that case you should also handle the unsuccessful cases. One simple way of doing that is checking the response object:

```
if (res.ok) {
  // The value resolved from the fetch() call is a Response object
  // and you can use .ok to check if the status code fell within the 2XX range
  // In which case it means it was successful.
  // Proceed as normal here
  // e.g. ... await res.text(), then parse JSON.
}
else {
  // The response status code fell outside 2XX range,
  // so something might have gone wrong.
  // Handle that case here
}
```

You can reference the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) for that and other useful properties.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation. So basically the error is coming from the server side. I just don't understand how it works with the deployed version but not my local version. I will try to work my way through what you have suggested here and hope I can get that done. Otherwise is there anyway to output the response I'm getting in the functioning deployed version, put it in a document myself and get the data from there?

Comment: @fabiocattolico, I'm not sure if this is what you want, but are you trying to work in a local development as though u are offline? In that case, usually a local development should not be hitting production APIs. One option is changing the URL to a local development API that you can run yourself. Use fetch(`${apiBaseUrl}/some/path`), where apiBaseUrl would be defined according to, say, your NODE_ENV variable (or from a central place where you store app configuration). You should have different app configuration values for each environment (development, test, production)

Comment: apparently the website that stored the json i fetched is not working properly anymore and since it was only small file I wrote the json myself and just mapped over it locally and it works just as well

Answer (score 1):

You suddenly got the error because the server didn't respond JSON data. It can be server error (500) or client bad data (4xx). Either reasons, your clients should be able to catch the error. If the response status is not OK (2xx HTTP status code), then you throw error instead of trying to parse JSON

```js
res.json()
```

There is a good example documentation at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#an_ajax_call)

Your logic can be rewritten as bellow:

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const exploreDataResponse = await fetch('https://links.papareact.com/pyp');

  if (!exploreDataResponse.ok) {
    // Throw error or handle logic when failed to fetch exploreData here
  }

  const exploreData = exploreDataResponse.json();

  const cardsDataResponse = await fetch('https://links.papareact.com/zp1');

  if (!cardsDataResponse.ok) {
    // Throw error or handle logic when failed to fetch cardData here
  }

  const cardsData = cardsDataResponse.json();

  return {
    props: {
      exploreData,
      cardsData,
    },
  };
}
```

**Note**: Depend on your application business to decide the data and error handling flow.

Comment: I will try to implement the code the way you mentioned and see what I can get. I hope I can make it work. So basically my problem is that the response is not what I'm expecting and I'm not prepared to handle a different kind of response? Also why does it still work in the deployed version but not locally? Shouldn't it be dysfunctional in both of them since they both request a response from the same source?

Comment: There can be from many reasons: 1/ CORS issue 2/ your clients don't  reach your server (network) 3/ your local client sends bad request (payload) 4/ your client is unauthorized, etc. You should open your `Dev tool (F12)` and check `Network` tab to see which request is failed and the response from server.